# Problems with counting spaces - Java

Tags: java, spaces

I'm having problems with the code below. It asks for the user to type in a sentence basically.

```
System.out.println("Enter a string containing spaces: ");
inputString = keyboard.next();
int lengthString = inputString.length();

System.out.println("You entered: " + inputString + "\n" + "The string length is: " + lengthString);
```

The problem is when it prints the statement, it only prints the first word, then counts the characters contained within the first word. I'm really new to Java, so I was wondering what should I do to make the program count the WHOLE string.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `nextLine()` method instead of `next()`:

```
inputString = keyboard.nextLine();
```

[`Scanner#next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()) method reads the next token. Tokens are considered to be separated by a delimiter. And the default delimiter of `Scanner` is as recognized by [`Character.isWhitespace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)).

Answer (score 2):

`keyboard.nextLine()` will pull in the entire line. `next()` only gets the next word. `next()` uses spaces by default to determine word sizes, but you can also set a custom delimiter if you want it to pull in different tokens.

Comment: This is, of course, assuming that `keyboard` is an instance of the `Scanner` class (which the OP didn't say)

Comment: very true, but the nature of the question makes it a safe assumption.

Comment: @gparyani Yes, it was an instance of the Scanner class. I'll be sure to note that next time I have a question.